# Improper Neutralization of Directives in Dynamically Evaluated Code ('Eval Injection')

Tags: python, eval, code-injection

Why am I receiving an eval injection error?

```
 if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   eval(sys.argv[1])(logger, *sys.argv[2:])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.

**Code:**

```
from ast import literal_eval as eval
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
     eval(sys.argv[1])(logger, *sys.argv[2:])
```

[Eval is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)